# pretty url html htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess, web

I am trying to redirect the page from mysite.com/page1?id=37773 to mysite.com/page1/37773.

I tried seraching on various blogs where i found them trying with php files but even when i copied and rewrite it wont work so i am here to get help of exprets .Thanks in advance.

what i have tried so far

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^page1/([a-zA-Z_-]+)\.html$ page?id=$1
```

Comment: Normally people want to go the other way. To present a nice url to the public and convert it locally using params.  You may have better luck at [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).  You also need to decide whether you are looking for a redirect (change in browser) or rewrite (internal redirection)

Comment: Is `mysite` intended to be a domain/hostname or a subdirectory? (Please use `example.com` if this is intended to be a domain.)

Comment: its domain bro @MrWhite thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
RewriteEngine ON
##External redirect rules here.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} mysite/page1\?id=(\S+)\s
RewriteRule ^ mysite/page1/%1? [R=301,L]

##Internal rewrite rules here...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^mysite/page1/([^/]+)/?$  mysite/page1?id=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: whats the difference between external and internal rules

Comment: `RewriteEngine On`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /doujin\?id=(\S+)\s
RewriteRule ^ /doujin/%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/doujin/([^/]+)/?$  /doujin?id=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
` it still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

what i did:-

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^file/([^/]+) $file.html?id=$1 [L,QSA] #displays mysite.com/file/29829 on browser while the request would be mysite.com/file?id=29829


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```